# how to aggregate and return zero in non exixtent where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like follows.

```
case_no    history_no
A22010021   1
A22010021   2
A22010021   3
```

```
select
    case 
        when max(history_no) is null 
            then 0 
        else max(history_no) end as max
from
    table
where
    case_no = 'A22010022' 
group by
    case_no
```

it returned

```
max
Null
```

when I set `case_no = 'A22010021'` it returned

```
max
3
```

My desired result is to get `1` where non-existent `case_no` is extracted.

```
max
0
```

What is the root cause of this?
Are there any ways to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: are you passing  'A22010021' value  (case_no = 'A22010021') programmatically?through python , java or another programming language

Comment: yes I will pass case_no as  `main.case_no = #{case_no}`  by mybatis. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think group by clause is not required in your use case.

```
select coalesce(max(history_no),0)
   from table_case_no where case_no='A220100234'
```

if you want to use group by clause then use below query to fill missing case no to put 0 value.

```
select case_no,max(history_no) max_history_no
    from table_case_no  where  case_no = 'A22010022' group by case_no
union
--below query for non-existent case no
select 'A22010022' as id,0 
    where not exists
    (
        select 1 from table_case_no where case_no='A22010022'
    )
    ;
```